# Como importar uma função de um módulo no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com problemas ao importar a função de um módulo e fazer uso da mesma.
Já me certifiquei de colocar o arquivo `__init__.py` na pasta. Mas não consigo fazer uso das funções.

O programa fará download do conteúdo HTML de uma página web, e faz um recorte de substrings (busca subs inicial e final) e recorta o entre elas. Também faz um acompanhamento offser da posição inicial e final de cada tag.

Meu programa (já com as funções do módulo, mas preciso retirá-las). Deixei para testarem a funcionalidade.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

Texto = requests.get('https://www.panvel.com/panvel/concor-hct-5mg125mg-30-comprimidos/p-622540')

#print("Status Code :", Texto.status_code)
#print(Texto.headers)


def PosEx(Substring,Texto,Offset):# Retorna resultado de corte em textos com offset e upper ignore
    return Texto.find(Substring,Offset)

Offset = 0

def CortaFora(Offset,Texto,Inicio,Fim): # Da o que está entre o inicio e o fim em determinado texto, respeitando offset e retornando offset inclusive.
    Inicial = Final = ''
    Inicial = PosEx(Inicio,Texto,Offset)+len(Inicio)
    # print('Pos Inicial:'+str(Inicial))
    Offset = Inicial
    Final = PosEx(Fim,Texto,Offset)
    # print('Pos Final:'+str(Final))
    Offset = Final
    return Texto[Inicial:Final].strip(' '), Offset

a = Texto.text
b = PosEx('<h1 class="item-title">',a, Offset)
print('Posição antes do corta Fora do Offset:' +str(b))
print('')
d,Offset = CortaFora(Offset, a,'<h1 class="item-title">','</h1>')
print(d)
print('')
print('Posicao Após Corta Fora do Offset:'+str(Offset))
```

Módulo que quero importar as funções `PosEx` e `CortaFora`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def PosEx(Substring,Texto,Offset):# Retorna resultado de corte em textos com offset e upper ignore
   # return Texto.find(Substring,Offset)

Offset = 0

def CortaFora(Offset,Texto,Inicio,Fim): # Da o que está entre o inicio e o fim em determinado texto, respeitando offset e retornando offset inclusive.
    Inicial = Final = ''
    Inicial = PosEx(Inicio,Texto,Offset)+len(Inicio)
    # print('Pos Inicial:'+str(Inicial))
    Offset = Inicial
    Final = PosEx(Fim,Texto,Offset)
    # print('Pos Final:'+str(Final))
    Offset = Final
    return Texto[Inicial:Final].strip(' '), Offset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É do mesmo modo que você faz os import de outros módulos, como você fez no seu próprio código com a lib `request`.

Vamos supor que os seus programas estão na mesma pasta.

Chamemos *function.py* (sugestão) o código com as funções:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def PosEx(Substring,Texto,Offset):
    """
    Retorna resultado de corte em textos com offset e upper ignore
    """
    return Texto.find(Substring,Offset)


def CortaFora(Offset,Texto,Inicio,Fim): 
    """
    Da o que está entre o inicio e o fim em determinado texto, respeitando offset
    e retornando offset inclusive.
    """
    Inicial = Final = ''
    Inicial = PosEx(Inicio,Texto,Offset)+len(Inicio)

    Offset = Inicial
    Final = PosEx(Fim,Texto,Offset)

    Offset = Final
    return Texto[Inicial:Final].strip(' '), Offset
```

Daí seu código principal ficaria assim:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

from function import PosEx, CortaFora

Texto = requests.get('https://www.panvel.com/panvel/concor-hct-5mg125mg-30-comprimidos/p-622540')

a = Texto.text
b = PosEx('<h1 class="item-title">',a, Offset)
print('Posição antes do corta Fora do Offset:' +str(b))
print('')
d,Offset = CortaFora(Offset, a,'<h1 class="item-title">','</h1>')
print(d)
print('')
print('Posicao Após Corta Fora do Offset:'+str(Offset))
```

Comment: Valeu Octávio!, deu certo, falta de atenção e experiencia, achei que fosse necessário chamar a função!!